# Perl5: returning several arrays/hashes from a sub

Tags: arrays, perl, perl-module

I wanna return several arrays and hashes from a sub. When I execute the sub, the first output array wraps all the outputs toguether and the others keep empty. Pls see this example:

The main file script.pl has:

```
use mymodule;
my (@o1, $o2)=mymodule::mysub;
print "o1 gives ".$o1[0]."  ".$o1[1]."  ".$o1[2];
print ", and o2 gives ".$o2."  \n";
```

File mymodule.pm looks like:

```
package mymodule;
sub mysub{
   my @a = ('a', 'b');
   my $b = 4;
   return (@a, $b);
   };
1;
```

Running script.pl will return o1 gives a  b  4, and o2 gives .

As you see, the correspondence of (@o1, $o2) to the values (@a, $b) returned by the module is not preserved.

Can anyone help me here?
Thx a lot!

---

thx for the explanation. However i cannot obtain the aimed result thru your suggestion. This code:

```
my ($o1_ref, $o2)=mysub;
my @o1 = @{$o1_ref};
print "o1 has ".$#o1." elements, o2 has ".$#o2." elements\n";
print "the first element of o1 is ".$o1->[0]."\n";

sub mysub{
   my @a = ('a', 'b');
   my $b = 4;
   return (\@a, $b);
   };
```

will return

```
o1 has -1 elements, o2 has -1 elements
the first element of o1 is
```

Thus it does not work for my perl 5.14.

Comment: It's impossible to return hashes and arrays from subs. the only think a sub can return is a list of scalars. It's up to you to devise a mean of recreating arrays and hashes from those scalar, but most people just return references (since those are scalars).

Comment: Easiest solution is to reverse the order of the returned values (`return $b, @a`). But the best solution is to return a reference to the array.

Answer (score 6):

It's time you learn about [References](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlreftut.html).

In Perl, you can return *a single list* of items from a subroutine or have *a  single list* of items for import. Only a single list, so if I attempt to return two arrays, Perl will put them into a single undifferentiated list:

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use feature qw(say);

my (@a, @b) = foo();
say join ": ", @a;
say join ": ", @b;

sub foo {
    my @first = qw(one two thee);
    my @second = qw(uno dos tres);
    return (@first, @second);
}
```

If you run this, you see that all of the data is returned to `@a` and nothing in `@b`.

References allow you to get around this *restriction*. A reference is simply a pointer to a place in memory that actually contains your data. That data could be a scalar (`$foo`), an array (`@foo`), or a hash (`%foo`). Since a location in memory is a single bit of data, references allow you to have an array that contains references to other arrays giving you an array of arrays. Or an array of hashes, or a hash of hashes, or all sorts of more complex data structures.

Let's look at your module and modify it's code a wee bit:

```
sub mysub{
   my @a = ('a', 'b');
   my $b = 4;
   return (\@a, $b);  # Look I added a backslash!
};
1;
```

That backslash says I am not returning an array. Instead, I am returning a location in memory where that array lives.

Now my program can do this:

```
my ($o1_ref, $o2) = mymodule::mysub();   # We'll talk about this later..
```

Another slight change in your code. My first item I'm returning isn't an array, but a reference to an array. Now, all I have to do is *dereference* it (that allows me access to the array):

```
my @o1 = @{ $o1_ref };
```

You dereference by putting the sigil of the data structure in front of your reference. You could even have done this:

```
my @o1 = @$o1_ref;
```

I don't like this because it's too easy to miss the `@$` combination. Using curly braces emphasizes that you are dereferencing an array reference.

Now, the rest of your program should work.

---

## Bonus Advice

Take a look at the [Exporter](http://perldoc.perl.org/Exporter.html) module. It's a standard module that comes with Perl.

This will allow you to *export* your functions from your module, so you don't have to prefix it with your module's name:

```
package Mymodule;              # Custom says to give modules capital names.

use strict;
use warnings;
use Exporter qw(import);

our @EXPORT_OK = qw(mysub);  # A list of all the subroutines you want main to use
```

sub mysub {
       my @a = qw(a b);
       my $b = 4;
       return (\@a, $b);
   }
1;

Now, all you have to do is say `mysub` in your main program:

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use Mymodule  qw(mysub);     # Include a list of what you want imported
use feature qw(say);          # Better "print" than "print"

my ($o1_ref, $o2) = mysub();
my @01 = @{ $o1_ref };
say "o1 gives ".$o1[0]."  ".$o1[1]."  ".$o1[2];
```

---

## In Response to [This](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22870956/368630)

Here's your code:

```
my ($o1_ref, $o2)=mysub;
my @o1 = @{$o1_ref};
print "o1 has ".$#o1." elements, o2 has ".$#o2." elements\n";
print "the first element of o1 is ".$o1->[0]."\n";

sub mysub{
   my @a = ('a', 'b');
   my $b = 4;
   return (\@a, $b);
};
```

- There's no array `@o2`, so `$#o2` is invalid.
- `$#` returns the LAST index and not the number of items. Use `scalar` function to get the number of items in an array.
- You've already dereferenced `@o1`. I did that to simplify the problem. Now, you're dereferencing the deferenced item when you do `$o1->[0]`.  By the way `$o1` doesn't exist as a variable.
- Always use `strict` and `warnings` pragmas. You'd catch a lot of the errors when you use these.
- Use `say` instead of print. You forgot the `\n` on the end again. If you're going to do that, use `say` with `use feature qw(say);`

#### Corrected Code

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use feature qw(say);

my ($o1_ref, $o2) = mysub();
my @o1 = @{$o1_ref};

say "\@o1 has " . scalar @o1 . " elemenets";
say "The first element of \@o1 is '$o1[0]'";
say "The second element of \@o1 is '$o1[1]'";
say "\$o2 is equal to  '$o2'";

sub mysub{
    my @a = ('a', 'b');
    my $b = 4;
    return (\@a, $b);
};
```

---

The output:

```
@o1 has 2 elemenets
The first element of @o1 is 'a'
The second element of @o1 is 'b'
$o2 is equal to  '4'
```

All correct.

Answer (score 2):

Or pass back a array ref

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
sub mysub{
   my @a = ('a', 'b');
   my $b = 4;
   return (\@a, $b);
 };

my ($o1, $o2) = mysub();
print "o1 gives ".${$o1}[0]."  ".${$o1}[1]."  ".$o1[2];
print ", and o2 gives ".$o2."  \n";
```

Comment: Sorry, dont know how to recover the returned values this way.

Comment: Did you mean how to deref back to an array? my @test = @{$o1}; Incidentally, I've not coded in perl for a while but I did always like to return hashes like the other answer suggested.

Answer (score 1):

The way you're doing it doesn't work with Perl. The `@a` is expanded and just the first part of the list that contains `@a` and `$b`.

Arrays, in assignment lists, are *"greedy"*. This works:

```
my ( $o2, @o1 ) = gimme();
```

But this doesn't:

```
my ( @o1, $o2 ) = gimme();
```

because everything is assigned to `@o1`. Whereas, the scalar-first assignment list pulls the first return off the list and assigns it to the scalar `$o2` and the rest to `@o1`.

Comment: well, it would pretty much keep clarity in my code if i can keep the outputs $o1 and $o2 as separate variables. If it is possible, i would prefer... thx

Answer (score 0):

Perl cannot return arrays from a sub.  Instead, return @a as an arrayref as follows:

```
package mymodule;
sub mysub{
  my @a = ('a', 'b');
  my $b = 4;
  return (\@a, $b);
};
```

Use the arrayref as follows:

```
use mymodule;
my ($o1, $o2)=mymodule::mysub;
print "o1 gives ".$o1->[0]."  ".$o1->[1]."  ".$o1->[2];
print ", and o2 gives ".$o2."  \n";
```

Bonus: If you need the index of the last element of the arrayref (perhaps you want to iterate through the arrayref to build back an array?):

```
$last_index = $#$o1;
```

As someone else recommended, I recommend you learn about Perl References.